# Can a Jenkins build be failed for coverage going down?

Tags: maven, build, jenkins

I've seen a number of posts on making a Maven-backed Jenkins build fail for a given project if a coverage threshold isn't met i.e. coverage must be at least 80% or the build fails.

I'm wondering if there is a way to configure Jenkins to fail a build if the coverage is lower than the last build i.e. if the coverage for build N is 20%, and N+1 is 19%, then the build fails. I don't want to put in an explicit threshold, but I want the coverage to stay steady or get higher over time.

Comment: This is an excellent question - exactly what I want as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Save last coverage percentage on the side. Use Groovy script (run via [Groovy Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Groovy+plugin)) that taps into [Jenkins Java API](http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/) to compare current coverage level with previous one and fail the build if it drops. If you seriously decide to go this way I can provide more details and code samples.

Comment: I was hoping for an easier answer than that. But, ok, maybe that's what I have to do. Where do you get the last coverage percentage out of rcov via Groovy? Or, bash, or a ruby script?

Comment: @Rob, We are talking about Ruby Metrics Plugin, right? Can you please provide me with a simple RCOV report so I can play with it?

Comment: Yes, Ruby Metrics plugin. Not sure how I'm supposed to provide you with a simple RCOV report?

Comment: no, I still don't understand what you want. It's not like a paste of an RCOV report from my jenkins site would help, and other RCOV reports all look kinda similar (and you wouldn't be able to play with a static page anyway). So you want me to host a simple project and put RCOV on it?

Comment: I do not work with Ruby - so I do not have a setup ready. That's why I need a sample report - just `index.html` page is enough it seems as it contains coverage info. I had done a quick Google search and did not find anything. A static report would help me as I can modify it slightly to 'simulate' a change in coverage. A report from your Jenkins is not a good idea as it most probably not simple. Write a very simple app (two files a few lines of code each) with a very simple test and run RCOV on it from the command line.

Comment: Why don't you just tell me what you are trying do to? If it's just an xpath to a place in a document, I can figure that out ...

Comment: Ok: I'd like to leverage [Ruby Metrics Plugin code](https://github.com/jenkinsci/rubyMetrics-plugin) in one of the following ways: either (1) simply extract the code that parses RCOV reports and then call it from Groovy inside the build; or (2) modify the plugin itself so that it fails the build if coverage drops.

Answer (score 9):

I haven't tried it, but assuming you are using maven cobertura plugin, I believe it can be configured to fail as documented [here](http://www.mojohaus.org/cobertura-maven-plugin/usage.html#Check).  Would jenkins not honour the failure?

I also see an [open feature request](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-11025) for this.

Comment: Sadly, codehaus is gone. I've updated the link to what I think is correct.

Answer (score 4):

Since the [1.6 version of Cobertura](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Cobertura+Plugin#CoberturaPlugin-VersionHistory) plugin, the issue has been fixed, and a new option appeared that allow the plugin to make the build failed if coverage is lower than previous build.

Answer (score 1):

This should be configurable in the configuration section of the plugin, that calculates the coverage. E.g. for the PMD plugin you can configure limits for unstable or failed build on the Job configuration page in the section "Build settings".

Comment: There are a bunch of coverage plugins. Do you know of one that has the functionality I'm asking about or are you speculating?

Comment: Ah ok, i thought you are already using one. I use Emma in one of my projects (there are a Maven and an Eclipse plugin for Emma), and with the Jenkins plugin you can define such limits, that you want (in the case you are looking for a code coverage analysis tool).

Comment: I'm fine with using EMMA, but can you be more specific about the exact property that I'd want to set to achieve what I set out in the question. I can't see that option.

Comment: Just checked my Jenkins, and indeed i was wrong. With the Jenkins Emma plugin you can only configure the Health Treshold, but not the build status. Maybe there is a plugin, where you can fail a build with a given Health. I'll check that.

Answer (score 0):

In NCover I specify a certain percent through a config file.  You could create a python script (or similar to alter that value if you wanted). Other than that I do not think there are any config variables