# Jest jenkins coverage

Tags: reactjs, testing, jenkins, code-coverage, jestjs

So i'm running test for jest successfully in Jenkins. Now we have some old projects that have zero coverage on them and i would like to start collecting coverage on changed files.

So here is my scenario, today i have 0% coverage over lets 100 lines of code, tomorrow i add 10 lines of code now i want to make sure that there is proper coverage for the 10 newly added lines of code.

If there is no coverage for the 10 new lines then i want to fail the build and force the developer to write test case.

If it is not possible on a line level i could also deal with file level, so if a file has changed it needs to have coverage for example.

Is something like this possible?

Comment: Have a look [here](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration.html#coveragethreshold-object) at all the possible options you have.

Comment: Yes i did read the docs but i couldn't find anything useful for my use case.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6486054/4875631) help?

Comment: Consider checking out [this](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Cobertura+Plugin) plugin as well. Even though they give java examples, looks like you can use the exporter and test previous build's coverage.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, you can use the [Cobertura Coverage Report](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Cobertura+Plugin) plugin in Jenkin to configure the thresholds that you would fail the build against on a post-build action in your build process.

The available threshold options are:

- package
- lines
- conditionals
- methods
- files

Our setup is configured such that each Pull Request below is build separately and if the thresholds below are not met then the build will fail so we won't be able to merge it in develop.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but this is not exactly what i'm looking for. I'm looking for a way to just check the changed files not the whole branch and fail it if the coverage is under a threshold. I want to see if the coverage degraded by new code

Comment: Not sure if there is such a tool but I am sure that this will cover your use case. Let's say that your coverage is at 80% and that you've added 2 new files with no tests in them. That will bring your overall coverage to, let's say 78% and then you will be able to fail the build

Comment: The problem is i have a monolith app with 1m+ lines of code that has 0 coverage. I don't want to force to get to 80% in one go. I want to have coverage over newly added code. I made it work with sonar and wuality gates in jenkins. It actually works pretty good!

Comment: This is the approach I followed as well. Let's assume that you start with just adding a few tests that bring your coverage up to 2%. Now you can configure your Cobertura plugin to fail a build if the tests are below 2%. A downside to this though is that every time your coverage goes up, you will have to change the plugin's configuration and increase your thresholds.

Comment: Correct, I didn't want to do that since we do 20/30 builds a day. With sonar it's all automated now, i also had to write some groovy for it though. If you are ever interested i can post the full solution

Comment: IMO you would only do that once, but interested to see how you solved this issue using sonar :), do you mind sharing that?

Comment: Look at the answer below where you will see a snapshot of the code how i've set it up

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure it out.

I've setup a sonarcloud instance and check my branch and PR against the setup rules.

From jenkins i'm now able to make an api call to sonar to get the analysis report on the new code only. Based on this it's up to me to fail the build or keep it running.

In jenkins i'm first running a normal sonarcloud scan,

then with the following step i'm getting the results back from the qualitygate inspection:

```
sh "cat .scannerwork/report-task.txt"
def props = readProperties file: '.scannerwork/report-task.txt'
def sonarServerUrl = props['serverUrl'].replaceAll('https://', '')
def ceTask
def analysisId
timeout(time: 1, unit: 'MINUTES') {
    waitUntil {
      def response = sh(script: """
          curl -v -X POST https://${SONAR}@${sonarServerUrl}/api/ce/task -d "id=${props["ceTaskId"]}"
        """, returnStdout: true)
        ceTask = readJSON text: response
        analysisId = ceTask["task"]["analysisId"]
        return "SUCCESS".equals(ceTask["task"]["status"])
    }
}

def response2 = sh(script: """
    curl -v -X POST https://${SONAR}@${sonarServerUrl}/api/qualitygates/project_status -d "analysisId=${analysisId}"
  """, returnStdout: true)

def qualitygate =  readJSON text: response2
```

That will leave me with an array of qualitygate, where i can check the status from and my final step is doing this:

```
if ("ERROR".equals(qualitygate["projectStatus"]["status"])) {
    error  "Quality Gate failure"
}
```

That will error the jenkins job and it will only check newly added code with the rules setup in sonar.