# jenkins declerative pipeline - fail build when coverage drops

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, cobertura

using declerative pipeline syntax in a [`Jenkinsfile`](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/jenkinsfile/) and publishing coverage report using [cobertura](https://plugins.jenkins.io/cobertura/) as follows

```
cobertura(
  coberturaReportFile: 'coverage/cobertura-coverage.xml', 
  enableNewApi: true,
  autoUpdateHealth: true,
  autoUpdateStability: true,
  failUnstable: true,
  failUnhealthy: true,
  failNoReports: true,
  onlyStable: false
)
```

also tried using [code coverage api](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/code-coverage-api/) as follows:

```
publishCoverage(
  failUnhealthy: true, 
  calculateDiffForChangeRequests: true,
  failBuildIfCoverageDecreasedInChangeRequest: true,
  failNoReports: true,
  adapters: [
    coberturaAdapter(path: 'coverage/cobertura-coverage.xml')
  ]
)
```

looking at all the documentation i could find, i wasn't able to figure out [what are the instructions to fail the build if coverage drops](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12472638) without using hard-coded thresholds.

would appreciate a reference or a code snippet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

enabling `autoUpdateHealth` in conjunction with hard-coded threshold would do the trick

```
cobertura(
  coberturaReportFile: 'coverage/cobertura-coverage.xml', 
  enableNewApi: true,
  autoUpdateHealth: true,
  autoUpdateStability: true,
  failUnstable: true,
  failUnhealthy: true,
  failNoReports: true,
  onlyStable: false
  conditionalCoverageTargets: '80, 0, 0',
  fileCoverageTargets: '80, 0, 0',
  lineCoverageTargets: '80, 0, 0',
  methodCoverageTargets: '80, 0, 0',
  packageCoverageTargets: '80, 0, 0',
)
```

Comment: This works well to show the coverage delta in the Jenkins UI, however it doesn't actually fail the build if coverage decreases. Is there some other step needed to make that happen?

Comment: @JoschaGötzer when the coverage increases, you will need to update (you can do it dynamically) the `cobertura()` block with the new values

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code we use to fail the build when coverage drops, key is setting *failBuildIfCoverageDecreasedInChangeRequest* and *applyThresholdRecursively* to true:

```
def coverage = ['applyThresholdRecursively':true, 'failBuildIfCoverageDecreasedInChangeRequest':true, /* ... etc. */]
coverage.globalThresholds = [[failUnhealthy: false, thresholdTarget: 'File', unhealthyThreshold: 1.0, unstableThreshold: 0.0]] //use your own values here
def coverageFilePath = 'path-to-your-coverage-file'

publishCoverage( 
 adapters: [coberturaAdapter(mergeToOneReport: true, path: coverageFilePath)],
 applyThresholdRecursively: coverage.applyThresholdRecursively, 
 failBuildIfCoverageDecreasedInChangeRequest: coverage.failBuildIfCoverageDecreasedInChangeRequest, 
 failNoReports: coverage.failNoReports,
 failUnhealthy: coverage.failUnhealthy,
 failUnstable: coverage.failUnstable,
 globalThresholds: coverage.globalThresholds 
)
```

[image]